# Visual Studio Code and subfolder-specific settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

My workspace root is a git repository containing couple of files and several git submodules. Each submodule have their own `.vscode/settings.json`. I was expecting VSCode to adjust its settings based on which submodule/subfolder I'm working in but it's not working as expected.

Is it possible?
I think it's possible if you use a multi-root workspace (which is supported since 1.18), but in my case I'd like to keep that single-root workspace.

Comment: looking for answer too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the time of writing the feature is just not implemented. There's a feature request in the program's issue tracker filed on 17 August 2017: [Monolithic structure, multiple project settings #32693](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32693).

Meanwhile, if you need it badly you have to abuse multi-root workspaces as described in [Diogo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305853/13508).

Answer (score 41):

I also couldn't find a decent answer for this, I did find an "hacky" workaround. I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── .gitignore
│   │   ├── hhapi
│   │   ├── manage.py
│   │   ├── .pylintrc
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   ├── venv
│   │   └── .vscode
│   └── crawler
│       ├── crawler-crontab
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── .gitignore
│       ├── hhcrawler
│       ├── .pylintrc
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── .scrapy
│       ├── scrapy.cfg
│       ├── venv
│       └── .vscode
├── docker-compose.development.yml
├── docker-compose.production.yml
├── .gitignore
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── househunter.code-workspace
└── .vscode
    └── settings.json
```

What I ended up doing was ignoring the `apps` directory on the project root and then add both apps to the workspace.

So the `./.vscode/settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "apps": true
      },
}
```

And the `househunter.code-workspace` file like so:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "apps/api"
        },
        {
            "path": "apps/crawler"
        },
        {
            "name": "root",
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

This is what I see on the editor:

[image: project structure on visual studio code explorer]

And it is indeed following the subprojects `settings.json`. This is far from being a great solution, but for the time being was the only way I found to achieve this - I'd also love to see someone document a proper solution for this. :)

Comment: Thanks Diogo.  This works great.  And gave me a lot more control over each sub-module.